# hide div on scroll down event wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to hide #header on scroll down event and then reappear on page scroll up.

page link :- http://elementsmart.com/product-category/jewellery/

the javascript code i used

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript">
$('#primary').scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 300) $('#header').fadeOut('slow');
if($(this).scrollTop() < 300) $('#header').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
#header-container { 
position:fixed !important;
margin-left:1.6% !important;
z-index:999 !important;
}
```

when someone scrolls primary need the header to hide.

tried on jsfiddle seems to be working perfect but on page its now showing .

can someone guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost done, change

```
$('#primary').scroll(function(){
```

to

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

Also wrap your code with

```
$(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Tried on your page in chrome and works. Ahh wrap your code with $(function(){ //your code here });

Comment: is header hiding on your browser ? what version chrome you using because its not working at all on my page ..... i am on version 27.0.1453.116

Comment: I mean is working on your site after running my code in chrome developer tools. See my post update.

Comment: yaaa datz the big confusion i tried the code in jsfiddle its working out there. running on my local machine as well .... but when m icluding the script in header.php of my wordpress install its not working

Comment: The code is good. Problem is with it's placement, you should first load jquery and then run your code.

Comment: thanks dude ..... m getting to understand the problem ..... working on it ...... u really been a life saver :)

Comment: can you tell me if i wanna hide multiple divs ( #logo, #topbar ) ..... what code changes would be required ? can i even hide div placed in a div using jquery ?

Comment: Multiple elements: "#a, #b", div inside div: "#a #b" or "#a > #b". Much more http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: hey i implemented all the code successfully. thanks for help. can you take a look at site now http://elementsmart.com and suggest me on how to insert a div #logonew in place of the logo div ...... via jquery

Comment: look here: http://api.jquery.com/ and solution: `$('#logo').replaceWith($('<div/>',{id:'logonew',text:'logonew'}));`

Comment: i forgot to mention i need to replace only upon scroll down.

Comment: if on scroll down put it inside previous function `$(window).scroll(function(){`

Comment: hey matt i am still stuck . i tried the code <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) $('#logo, #topbar, .cart-label').fadeOut('slow');
 $('#logo').replaceWith($('<div/>',{id:'logonew',text:'logonew'}));
    if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) $('#logo, #topbar, .cart-label').fadeIn('slow');
    })
    });
</script> but still no success it simply replaces the logo div.when i hide the logo div upon scroll the menu shifts to left.i wanna simply insert a smaller logo to the place so menu wont shift. can u help.

Comment: i came quite close <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) $('#logo, #topbar, .cart-label').fadeOut('slow');
 $('#logo').css({'background-image':'url(http://elementsmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/resized.png)','background-repeat':'no-repeat'})
    })
    });
</script> can u guide further ?